# Find$P(X>Y^2)$ for $f(x,y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find $P(X>Y^2)$ for $f(x,y)=9x^2y^2$
where $0<y<1$ and $-y<x<y$

I know that $P(Y^2<X)=P(-\sqrt{X}<Y<\sqrt{X})$. Is this useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly.  Just use:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X>Y^2) & = \int_0^1 \mathsf P(X>y^2\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1\int_{y^2}^{y} f(x,y)\operatorname dx\operatorname d y
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is the first line true?

Comment: Oppie. It was not quite right.  It's by the definition of probability as an expectation of an indicator function. $$\mathsf P(X>Y^2) = \mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X>Y^2}) =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathsf 1_{X>Y^2}\mid Y))$$